# Передача переменной в представление

Tags: php, html, laravel

Я написала представление шапки сайта:

```html
 <div class="bg-light">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-mgray">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route("home") }}">{{ config('app.name') }}</a>

        <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-toggle-cbox">


        <label class="navbar-toggler" for="navbar-toggle-cbox" data-toggle="collapse"
               data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
           aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </label>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    @admin
                    <li class="nav-item @isroute('admin') active @endisroute">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('admin.index') }}">Панель администратора</a>
                    </li>
                    @endadmin
                  @moderator
                    <li class="nav-item @isroute('admin') active @endisroute">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('admin.index') }}">Панель модератора</a>
                  </li>
                    @endmoderator
                    @auth
         <li class="nav-item @isroute('profile.tickets') active @endisroute">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('profile.tickets') }}">Помощь</a>
                        </li>
                 @endauth

                </ul>
         
          @search
            
               <div class="col-md-02">
                    <form action="{{route('search')}}" method="POST" class="form-inline h-100">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                 <div class="input-group w-100">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control" id="search" name="search"
                                   placeholder="Что Вы ищете?" value="{{app('request')->input('query')}}">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn  btn-info">Поиск</button>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
           
          @endsearch

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                     @auth

                        <li class="nav-item @isroute('profile.notifications') active @endisroute">
                            <a href="{{route('profile.notifications')}}" class="nav-link">
                                <span @if(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->count() > 0) class="text-warning" @endif><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> {{auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->count()}}</span>
                            </a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="nav-item @isroute('profile.purchases') active @endisroute">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('profile.purchases') }}">
                                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart mr-2"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item @isroute('profile.index') active @endisroute">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('profile.index') }}">{{auth()->user()->username}}</a>
                        </li>

                        <form class="form-inline" action="{{route('auth.signout.post')}}" method="post">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <button class="btn btn-link text-muted my-0" type="submit" style="text-decoration: none;">Выйти</button>
                        </form>
                        @else
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('auth.signin')}}">Войти</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('auth.signup')}}">Регистрация</a>
                        </li>
                        @endauth
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-nav-blue">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="hamburger-menu">
                            <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
                            <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                            <ul class="menu__box">
                                @include ('includes.categories')
                             </ul>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item-blue">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="">#</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="">#</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
</nav>
```

В этом представлении я пытаюсь инклудить представление категорий.
Как только я это делаю - у сайта работает главная страница и я могу зайти в любую категорию. Все прекрасно. Но как только я пытаюсь посетить какие либо другие страницы - я получаю ошибку:

> Undefined variable: categories (View: ###/resources/views/includes/categories.blade.php)

Я могу заинклудить список категорий хоть посреди домашней страницы и весь сайт прекрасно работает, но как только я пытаюсь сделать это в панели навигации - все перестает работать.

Я совсем запуталась в какое представление и каким образом я должна передать переменную $categories. И вообще потеряла логическую цепочку связи подключения представления и того, что переменная перестает передаваться.

Привожу код `web.php` и `indexcontroller.php`:

```php
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::name('auth.')->group(function () {
    include 'auth.php';
});
Route::prefix('admin') -> group(function (){
    Route::middleware(['admin_panel_access'])->group(function () {
        include 'admin.php';
    });
});
// Profile routes
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('banned', 'ProfileController@banned')->name('profile.banned');
    Route::middleware(['is_banned']) -> group(function(){
        include 'profile.php';
    });
});
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@home')->name('home');
Route::get('/category/{category}', 'IndexController@category') -> name('category.show');





Route::get('/login', 'IndexController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('/confirmation', 'IndexController@confirmation')->name('confirmation');

Route::get('setview/{list}', 'IndexController@setView') -> name('setview');

// Product routes
Route::get('product/{product}', 'ProductController@show') -> name('product.show');
Route::get('product/{product}/rules', 'ProductController@showRules') -> name('product.rules');
Route::get('product/{product}/feedback', 'ProductController@showFeedback') -> name('product.feedback');
Route::get('product/{product}/delivery', 'ProductController@showDelivery') -> name('product.delivery');
Route::get('product/{product}/vendor', 'ProductController@showVendor') -> name('product.vendor');

// category routes
Route::get('category/{category}', 'IndexController@category') -> name('category.show');

// vendor routes
Route::get('vendor/{user}', 'IndexController@vendor') -> name('vendor.show');

Route::get('vendor/{user}/feedback', 'IndexController@vendorsFeedbacks') -> name('vendor.show.feedback');

Route::post('search','SearchController@search')->name('search');
Route::get('search','SearchController@searchShow')->name('search.show');
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Marketplace\Cart;
use App\Marketplace\FeaturedProducts;
use App\Marketplace\ModuleManager;
use App\Marketplace\Payment\Escrow;
use App\Marketplace\Payment\VergeCoin;
use App\Product;
use App\Vendor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/**
 * Controller for all always public routes
 *
 * Class IndexController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handles the index page request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function home() {

        if (!ModuleManager::isEnabled('FeaturedProducts'))
            $featuredProducts = null;
        else
            $featuredProducts = FeaturedProducts::get();

        return view('welcome', [
            'productsView' => session() -> get('products_view'),
            'products' => Product::frontPage(),
            'categories' => Category::roots(),
            'featuredProducts' => $featuredProducts
        ]);
    }





    /**
     * Redirection to sing in
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function login() {

        return redirect()->route('auth.signin');
    }

    public function confirmation(Request $request) {
        return view('confirmation');
    }

    /**
     * Show category page
     *
     * @param Category $category
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function category(Category $category) {
        return view('category',  [
            'productsView' => session() -> get('products_view'),
            'category' => $category,
            'products' => $category->childProducts(),
            'categories' => Category::roots(),
        ]);

    }



    /**
     * Show vendor page, 6 products, and 10 feedbacks
     *
     * @param Vendor $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function vendor(Vendor $user) {
        return view('vendor.index',[
            'vendor' => $user->user
        ]);

    }
    /**
     * Show page with vendors feedbacks
     *
     * @param Vendor $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function vendorsFeedbacks(Vendor $user) {
        return view('vendor.feedback', [
            'vendor' => $user->user,
            'feedback' => $user->feedback()->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(20),
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Sets in session which view are we using
     *
     * @param $list
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function setView($list)
    {
        session() -> put('products_view', $list);
        return redirect() -> back();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Файл `app/providers/AppService/Provider.php` должен выглядеть так

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('categories', (new \App\Category)->roots());

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
            $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
}
```